# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a list from C# web method with ajax (code below), the list is returned fine, but after the success method is done, it gives me an error - (Cannot read property 'length' of undefined) in the jquery (screenshot below)

Am I missing something ??

```
function getMainParentMenus() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Mainpage.aspx/getLeftMainNavParentMenus",

        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
            parentMenuss = msg.d;
        }, //It goes to the screenshot below after this bracket
        error: function (error) {
            alert("An error has occured while fetching the Left Nav Parent Menus");
        }
    });

};
```

[image]

The method above is called by the below method.

```
    var parentMenuss;
    var listOfSubMenus;
    function bindLeftNavMenu() {
//    var parentMenus = getMainParentMenus();


getMainParentMenus();



    var html = "<div id='accordian'> ddd";

    $.each(parentMenuss, function () {

        html += " <h3 class='accordianHeader' href='" + this['URL'] + "'>" + this['Title'] + "</h3>  ";
        alert("okK");
        $.each(listOfSubMenus, function () {
            html += "<div class='accordianContent'><a href='" + this['URL']  + "'>" + this['Title'] + "</a>";
        });

    });
    html += "</div>";
    $("#leftNavigationMenu").append(html);
 };
```

EDIT :

the data in the alert in the first block of code above is displayed like so 
[image]

and in the chrome debugger : 
[image]

Comment: It looks like you are having an asynchronous issue (i,e, `parentMenuss` isn't defined when `$.each` is called), what does the data look like that is returned from the ajax call?

Comment: Or said another way: `parentMenuss` is *not set* until after the XHR success callback runs. Make sure the code that uses `parentMenuss` is executed *after* (i.e. from within or response to) the XHR success callback.

Comment: `parentMenuss === undefined` and `$.each(undefined,function(){...})` isn't going to work.

Comment: question edited with how the data is displayed

Comment: Well, using alert() in debugging purpose is generally not agreat idea, use your console with console.log() e.g. BTW, your issue is quite simple, you cannot return value from async request, see duplicate topic for how to use ajax result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `getMainParentMenus` is using AJAX it is asynchronous. Your next line of code after calling `getMainParentMenus` will be executed *before* the `.success` part of your AJAX call, so it will be executed *before* `parentMenuss` has been populated.

There are a few ways you can tackle this, one way would be to pass the callback function to `getMainParentMenus`, something like this:

```
function getMainParentMenus(myCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Mainpage.aspx/getLeftMainNavParentMenus",

        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
            parentMenuss = msg.d;
            if (callback && typeof(callback)==="function") {
                callback();
            }
        }, //It goes to the screenshot below after this bracket
        error: function (error) {
            alert("An error has occured while fetching the Left Nav Parent Menus");
        }
    });

};
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
var html = "<div id='accordian'> ddd";

getMainParentMenus(function() { 
    $.each(parentMenuss, function () {
        html += " <h3 class='accordianHeader' href='" + this['URL'] + "'>" + this['Title'] + "</h3>  ";
        alert("okK");
        $.each(listOfSubMenus, function () {
            html += "<div class='accordianContent'><a href='" + this['URL']  + "'>" + this['Title'] + "</a>";
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code for rendering the menus is being executed immediately after `getMainParentMenus();` Javascript does not wait for the ajax call to complete before moving on to the next block. It is operating asynchronously, as others have mentioned in the comments.

Your code has to wait for the ajax call to complete before trying to display the data.

jQuery supports deferred execution and promises, so you can create code that will not execute until other code has completed. This is the preferred way of handling asynchronous operations.

Try this:

```
function getMainParentMenus() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Mainpage.aspx/getLeftMainNavParentMenus",

        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    }, //It goes to the screenshot below after this bracket
        error: function (error) {
            alert("An error has occured while fetching the Left Nav Parent Menus");
        }
    });
    return request;
}


var parentMenuss;
var listOfSubMenus;
function bindLeftNavMenu() {

    getMainParentMenus().success(function (result) {
        var html = "<div id='accordian'> ddd";

        $.each(parentMenuss, function () {
            html += " <h3 class='accordianHeader' href='" + this['URL'] + "'>" + this['Title'] + "</h3>  ";
            alert("okK");
            $.each(listOfSubMenus, function () {
                html += "<div class='accordianContent'><a href='" + this['URL']  + "'>" + this['Title'] + "</a>";
            });
        });
        html += "</div>";
        $("#leftNavigationMenu").append(html);
    });
}
```